# Can't use my old my.cnf from MySQL 5.5.38 in newer 5.6.19

Tags: centos, mysql

Ok so I have been trying to upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6. I have been given this set my.cnf file (see below). I was able to uninstall the MySQL 5.5 rpms and install the 5.6. When I reload the back up my.cnf file the mysql server does not want to start. Is there something wrong with this file? I have ran `mysql_install_db`. However, I cannot get the server to start up with my `my.cnf` file. I have looked in the error log, but it hasn't been copying anything recent to it. The `my.cnf` works when it is blank.

This is what my `my.cnf` file from MySQL 5.5 looks like (see below). I need this my.cnf file to work on the 5.6 version. Anyone have any incite?

```
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /u02/mysqldata1/mysqld_3306.sock
#
#
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /u02/mysqldata1/mysqld_3306.sock
nice            = 0
#
#
[mysqld]
#performance_schema=1
user            = mysql
socket          = /u02/mysqldata1/mysqld_3306.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /u02/mysqldata1/data/3306
tmpdir          = /u02/mysqldata/tmp
skip-external-locking
character_set_server    = utf8
lower_case_table_names  = 1
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
max_allowed_packet              = 64M
max_connections                 = 500
max_connect_errors              = 100
max_heap_table_size             = 256M
tmp_table_size                  = 256M
net_buffer_length               = 8K
sort_buffer_size                = 4M
read_buffer_size                = 1M
read-rnd-buffer-size    = 2M
table_cache                     = 1024
table-definition-cache  = 512
thread_stack                    = 256K
thread_cache_size               = 256
sql-mode                        = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
query_cache_size                = 64M
query_cache_limit               = 4M
#
# MyISAM Configuration
#
key_buffer_size                 = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 128M
ft_min_word_len                 = 3
myisam_recover_options          = BACKUP,FORCE
myisam_repair_threads           = 6
myisam_use_mmap                 = 1
#
# General Logging
#
log_error                       = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/err/error.log
long_query_time                 = 1
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/slow/mysql_slow.log
general_log                     = 0
general_log_file                = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/general/mysql_general.log
#
# Binary Log and Replication Configuration
#
log_bin                        = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/bin/mysql-bin.log
log-bin-index         = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/bin/mysql_bin.index
binlog-cache-size     = 256K
binlog_format         = ROW
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
relay-log               = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/relay/mysql_bin.log
relay-log-index         = /u02/mysqldata/mysqllog/3306/relay/mysql_bin.index
expire-logs-days        = 7
max_binlog_size         = 100M
sync_binlog             = 0
#
# Replication
#
server-id=129206
#log-slave-updates
#replicate-ignore-db = mysql
#replicate-ignore-table=
slave_transaction_retries = 20
#slave-skip-errors = 1062
#auto_increment_increment = 3
#auto_increment_offset = 3


#
# InnoDB Configuration
#

innodb_file_format                      = Barracuda
innodb_file_format_max                  = Barracuda

innodb_data_home_dir                    = /u02/mysqldata1/innodb/3306/data
innodb_log_group_home_dir               = /u02/mysqldata1/innodb/3306/log
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_data_file_path                   = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

transaction-isolation                   = READ-COMMITTED

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size                  = 8M
innodb_log_file_size                    = 512M

innodb_buffer_pool_size                 = 500M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         = 128M

innodb_flush_method                     = O_DSYNC
innodb_thread_concurrency               = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout                = 60
innodb-open-files                       = 500
innodb-support-xa                       = 0


#
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 128M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 1G
```

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your questions correctly.

Comment: i reformated it.

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM does your server have? On a mostly InnoDB database the 500M is too high for a key buffer size. I generally start with 32M. You can not run MySQL with it set to 0.

If the innodb_buffer_size + the key_buffer_size = > RAM then you will have problems.

Also I generally need this setting in a secure network: 
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0

A good starting place for my.cnf is here: https://tools.percona.com/wizard

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to comment out these two lines in the my.ini

table_cache and max_connection

Hope that helps.